# How do I bulk remove all of the videos from my watch later list on YouTube?

Tags: youtube, youtube-watch-later

I already have 200+ videos at watch later list on YouTube. So, I stopped adding videos to my watch later list to avoid messing it even more.

Now I simply want to remove them all so I can start fresh again, only with things I really want to watch later, but there is no option to remove them all, and I won’t hurt my finger clicking there.

A userscript could do the trick also I guess.

Comment: Can’t test it, but see if [this method](http://www.reddit.com/r/youtube/comments/2jfdzf/how_to_remove_all_videos_from_watch_later/cp9cz9q) works.

Comment: @Alex works very well!! I think you can copy that instructions here and put the link, will be the best answer; I found a way to do it [with javascript](http://www.reddit.com/r/youtube/comments/2jfdzf/how_to_remove_all_videos_from_watch_later/) `var el = document.getElementsByClassName('pl-video-edit-remove'); for (var i=0;i<el.length; i++) { el[i].click(); }` but this may break some day; I just expect that funcionality you found doesnt get removed one day; thx!

Comment: @AquariusPower they've made the onClick method unusable by writing `; return false;`. I'm not sure where/how they're handling click events because I couldn't see any other event listeners

Comment: The onClick is disabled while waiting for the server's response, so you can wrap it in an interval and wait for it to finish on it's own
`setInterval(function(){var el = document.getElementsByClassName('pl-video-edit-remove'); el[0].click();
},1000)`

Comment: Works in July 2018. To be clear, you must click on 'Edit' for this to work; playlist will have `disable_polymer=true` flag set in url. Only caveat: You may have click the 'Load More' button.

Comment: I removed 1000+ videos by this.(PC)
`function getRandom(obj) {
return obj[Math.floor(Math.random() * obj.length)]
}
setInterval(function(){
console.log("remove");
var btns = document.getElementsByClassName('pl-video-edit-remove');
getRandom(btns).click();
}, 1181);
setInterval(function(){
console.log("laodmore");
var btns = document.querySelectorAll(".load-more-button.yt (http://load-more-button.yt/)-uix-load-more");
getRandom(btns).click();
}, 2331);`

Comment: @taku_oka that sounds like an answer not a comment :>

Comment: @AquariusPower  I can't see the form to answer..

Comment: You can use JavaScript to remove them. https://gist.github.com/astamicu/eb351ce10451f1a51b71a1287d36880f

Comment: [This](https://github.com/ozgrozer/useful-scripts/blob/master/youtube/remove-all-videos-from-watch-later.js) one works perfectly.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> I just found out a method that is much easier and works 100% of the time! In your browser go to your Watch Later playlist and click the menu (the three dots in the right top corner) and add to playlist. Create a new playlist and name it something easy (I named it WL for example). Now go to that playlist and go to the same menu and instead of adding it to a playlist uncheck Watch Later. Now your Watch Later playlist is cleared and you can delete the temorary playlist you just created. Hope this helps some people!

[Source](http://www.reddit.com/r/youtube/comments/2jfdzf/how_to_remove_all_videos_from_watch_later/cp9cz9q).

Comment: Is this still valid? Per a suggested edit, this may not be working now.

Comment: This is not working as on 2017-05-08

Comment: This works as of July 2017. Just to reiterate--after you create a new playlist, go to Watch Later, click the dots, click "add all to...", and check the new playlist, now go to your new playlist, click the dots, click "add all to..." and uncheck Watch Later.

Comment: The only extra thing you need to do if you're using the new Polymer interface is to first hit the edit button.

Comment: These instructions are unclear

Comment: unfortunately, as of 2020, this button just errs out now. It seems JS is the only option.